# Vertical and Horizontal alignment

Tags: html, css, layout, presentation

I am designing an html page where I need to display my inserted images. I want the arrangement of images in such a way :

```
Image1 Image2 Image3    
Image4 Image5 Image6    
Image7 Image8 Image9

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Display Images</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  {% for image in images %}
    <div> 
      <img src={{ self.item_.images }}>
     </div>
  {% endfor %}
 </body>
<html>
```

All the images there after aligns in the same order. First row with three images, then automatically break, then next row.

Please help. 
Best Regards

Comment: Any relevant code you have tried so far?

Comment: Do you know how many images you'll display? Is it 9 everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply float every image left...then clear after every third image in order to force the next three to a new line.

You can use the CSS `nth-child` selector for this, as outlined below. This escapes the need for setting specific widths for each image, and a parent container.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2LMa/)

CSS

```
img{
    float:left;
}
img:nth-child(3n+1){
    clear:left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This also is smart when I am not sure about number of images.. This is really helpful.

Comment: Best answer by far, simple & CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s2VGa/)

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
    <img src='http://www.openvms.org/images/samples/130x130.gif'>

    <img src='http://www.openvms.org/images/samples/130x130.gif'>

    <img src='http://www.openvms.org/images/samples/130x130.gif'>

    <img src='http://www.openvms.org/images/samples/130x130.gif'>

    <img src='http://www.openvms.org/images/samples/130x130.gif'>

    <img src='http://www.openvms.org/images/samples/130x130.gif'>

    <img src='http://www.openvms.org/images/samples/130x130.gif'>

    <img src='http://www.openvms.org/images/samples/130x130.gif'>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    }

.container img{
    float:left;
    padding:1px;

}
```

Comment: Yes this one Exactly.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
       Image1 (fll) Image2 (fll) Image3 (fll)    
(clear)Image4 (fll) Image5 (fll) Image6 (fll)    
(clear)Image7 (fll) Image8 (fll) Image9 (fll)
```

Where :

```
fll   - float: left
clear - clear: both
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can find the idea** [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_gallery.asp)

Then I customize it for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .container 
    {
        width:500px;
    }
    div.img
    {
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #0000ff;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }   
    div.img img
    {
        display: inline;
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    }
    div.img a:hover img {border: 1px solid #0000ff;}
    div.desc
    {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: normal;
        width: 120px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="klematis_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis2_big.htm"><img src="klematis2_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis3_big.htm"><img src="klematis3_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis4_big.htm"><img src="klematis4_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your images to have a fixed size?

If not:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    img {
        width: 33%;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src=""><img src=""><img src="">
<img src=""><img src=""><img src="">
<img src=""><img src=""><img src="">
</body>
</html>
```

If yes: (You might need to consider a fixed container width.)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .main-container {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    img {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <img src=""><img src=""><img src="">
        <img src=""><img src=""><img src="">
        <img src=""><img src=""><img src="">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Floating allows the images to fill a row. Fixed with of images and the container makes it possible to determine how many images there will be in the row.

If you want to follow responsive design, you could add break point to your page so that in smaller screen sizes your grid of images depends on available space.

Normally you will want to have fixed size for your images that is their actual size. Otherwise the displayed quality of the images might be bad.